# Implementing Delete Button For Each Item In List (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, list

Hi as part of an exercise I have to create a todo list with the following implementation.
When I click the TODO button a prompt box appears where I type in a goal that I have in mind, it then gets added to a list and the item count is set to how many items are in the list.

The list also has a delete button and a check button for each item. The check button is used to determine if a goal has been complete and the delete button is used to remove a specific goal.

Unfortunately my delete button appears to not work. When I click it, instead of deleting the selected item, it deletes the first item in the list. I'm still not sure why. Could anyone provide the correct code to fix this? Thanks.

```js
const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')

//This function creates a new list element
function newTodo() {
  var clicks = document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;
  var item = prompt("Please enter a goal", " ")
  if(item == null){
    return cheese
  }
  clicks ++;
  itemCountSpan.innerHTML = clicks;
  list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML + "<li id = 'clicks'> <input type = checkbox onclick = 'checker()' class = 'todo-checkbox'>Goal: " + item +
  "</input>" + "<button class = 'todo-delete' value = clicks onclick = 'deleteToDo(this.value)'>Delete</button></li>"

}
//This function sets the unchecked count
function checker(){
    var Total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++){
      if (!document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].checked){
        Total ++;
        uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = Total;
      }
  }
}
//This function deletes a list element selected
function deleteToDo(sel_id){

  list.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName("li")[sel_id]);
  var clicks = document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;
  itemCountSpan.innerHTML = clicks;

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.center {
  align-self: center;
}

.flow-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.title, .controls, .button {
  flex: none;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.todo-list {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.todo-delete {
  margin: 10px;
}

.todo-checkbox {
  margin: 10px;
}

.todo-container {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.todo-container:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <button class="button center" onClick="newTodo(); checker()">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. Just pass the `li` element to be removed via the `onclick` handler and remove it from the `ul` element.

```js
const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')

//This function creates a new list element
function newTodo() {
  var clicks = document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;
  var item = prompt("Please enter a goal", " ")
  if(item == null){
    return cheese
  }
  clicks ++;
  itemCountSpan.innerHTML = clicks;
  list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML + "<li id = 'clicks'> <input type = checkbox onclick = 'checker()' class = 'todo-checkbox'>Goal: " + item +
  "</input>" + "<button class = 'todo-delete' value = clicks onclick = 'deleteToDo(this.parentElement)'>Delete</button></li>"

}
//This function sets the unchecked count
function checker(){
    var Total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++){
      if (!document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].checked){
        Total ++;
        uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = Total;
      }
  }
}
//This function deletes a list element selected
function deleteToDo(elem){

  list.removeChild(elem);

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.center {
  align-self: center;
}

.flow-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.title, .controls, .button {
  flex: none;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.todo-list {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.todo-delete {
  margin: 10px;
}

.todo-checkbox {
  margin: 10px;
}

.todo-container {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.todo-container:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <button class="button center" onClick="newTodo(); checker()">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got some syntax errors in the line where you build your new list li, just placement of quotes. I think it should be like this so that the variable clicks is actually set as the id and the value instead of the word 'clicks'.

```
list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML + "<li id = '" + clicks + "'> <input type = 'checkbox' onclick = 'checker()' class = 'todo-checkbox'>Goal: " + item +
  "</input>" + "<button class = 'todo-delete' value = '" + clicks + "' onclick = 'deleteToDo(this.parentElement)'>Delete</button></li>"
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` needed to be set to the actual variable in that function. So all I did was:

```js
... value = " + (clicks-1) ...
//We use (clicks - 1) because the array is 0 based but clicks was previously incremented.
```

```js
const classNames = {
  TODO_ITEM: 'todo-container',
  TODO_CHECKBOX: 'todo-checkbox',
  TODO_TEXT: 'todo-text',
  TODO_DELETE: 'todo-delete',
}

const list = document.getElementById('todo-list')
const itemCountSpan = document.getElementById('item-count')
const uncheckedCountSpan = document.getElementById('unchecked-count')

//This function creates a new list element
function newTodo() {
  var clicks = document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;
  var item = prompt("Please enter a goal", " ")
  if(item == null){
    return cheese
  }
  clicks++;
  itemCountSpan.innerHTML = clicks;
  list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML + "<li id = 'clicks'> <input type = checkbox onclick = 'checker()' class = 'todo-checkbox'>Goal: " + item +
  "</input>" + "<button class = 'todo-delete' value = " + (clicks-1) + " onclick = 'deleteToDo(this.value)'>Delete</button></li>"

}
//This function sets the unchecked count
function checker(){
    var Total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("input").length; i++){
      if (!document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i].checked){
        Total ++;
        uncheckedCountSpan.innerHTML = Total;
      }
  }
}
//This function deletes a list element selected
function deleteToDo(sel_id){
  list.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName("li")[sel_id]);
  var clicks = document.getElementsByTagName("input").length;
  itemCountSpan.innerHTML = clicks;

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.center {
  align-self: center;
}

.flow-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.title, .controls, .button {
  flex: none;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.todo-list {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.todo-delete {
  margin: 10px;
}

.todo-checkbox {
  margin: 10px;
}

.todo-container {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.todo-container:first-of-type {
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container center">
      <h1 class="center title">My TODO App</h1>
      <div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <button class="button center" onClick="newTodo(); checker()">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```